# Seating n persons and their associated person not together

Tags: combinatorics

I have come across a problem on the above topic, and its solution is not clear to me. Initial part of non-understandable portion of solution, along with the problem is stated below, and I hope that if that part is understood, the rest of the (not stated below) solution will be understood easily.

Problem : Let there be $N$ ambassadors, and with each of them are an associated set of one assistant. Now, there are a total of $2N$ persons; with need to not allow an ambassador and his assistant sit together while seated on a huge circular table.

Solution : There are $2(N!)$ ways to seat all $2N$ people. Can choose either an even (starting from 2nd position) or odd seating of the ambassadors, and vice-versa for the assistants.

Solution (Initial part of the 'Not-understandable' portion) : 
Need count all such configurations in which 'bad' seating can occur, by using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Identifying the set of such 'bad' seatings :

$K_{2i-1}$ = { seatings with assistant $e_i$ in seat $2i - 1$}, for $1\le i \le N.$

$K_{2i}$ = { seatings with assistant $e_i$ in seat $2i + 1$}, for $1\le i \lt N.$

$K_{2N}$ = { seatings with assistant $e_N$ in seat $1$}.

If $A \subset [2N] = ${$1,2,...,2N$}, let $K_A = \cap_{i\in A}K_i$ denote the seatings with $e_i$ in a wrong seat for all $i \in A.$ The set labelled $K_0 = S,$ the set of $N!$ possible seatings of the assistants.

The number of seatings in $K_A$ is not easy to compute as the set must be empty if $A$ contains some $j$ and $j+1$ or $1$ and $2N$.

If $A$ contains $2k-1$ and $2k$, then $e_k$ is meant to sit in seats $2k -1$ and $2k+ 1$, an impossibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't specify that ambassadors can't be next to one another.

Since they are seated in a circle, there are $(2n-1)!$ unrestricted seatings. Treat an ambassador and associated assistant as glued together as a "couple" in $2$ ways, then applying inclusion-exclusion,

# of ways = total ways - at least one "couple" together + at least two "couples" together - ...

$$ = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\cdot 2^k\binom{n}{k}(2n-1-k)!$$

Comment: I will see by your new view-point that there can be ambassadors sitting together, and I hope that assistants sitting together. May be it forms the approach of the solution given.

Comment: I have taken the chairs to be unnumbered. If they are numbered, you need to multiply the answer by $2n$. Btw, this is the *relaxed* menage problem, (since ambassadors and assistants needn't alternate), and results tally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I'm right so could anyone let me know if I've made any errors.

Think about the ambassadors as capital letters and the assistants as lowercase letters in the string $AbDaEdBe\ldots$. We can't put $A$ next to $a$ nor $B$ next to $b$ and so on, but also, the first letter of the string is adjacent to the last letter. Assuming WLOG the first letter is A, if there's $2n$ letters, theres $2n$ places to put $A$, $(2n-1-2)$ places to put $a$, then there's $(2n-2)$ places to put $B$, and $(2n-3-2) $ places to put $b$, and so on. So the total number of arrangements is $2n(2n-3)(2n-2)(2n-5)\ldots=(2n)!/(2n-1)$.

Comment: But, the solution approach is what I needed most to understand. Also, your approach of having (2n-2) places confuses me, as either odd or even seating ordering is available for the ambassadors (capital letters).

Comment: Also, the solution is linked to $me \acute nage$ numbers; the formula is the same.